# Cubecart and Paypal IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

We seem to be having an issue with a customer who has a cubecart store and Paypal IPN. The issue is that the IPN notification URL's were working and changing the order status upon a successful purchase, but now it seems to have stopped working. The orders go through ok and the item appears in the Paypal account, but it is not updating the order status on the store (goes from pending to processing automatically).

Comment: You will need to add more detail if you hope to get a good answer. Have you checked logs etc? Anything showing up? Is it possible to post the relevant code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

Check your IPN history in your account.  First verify that the IPN is being sent out.  If the IPN log shows the IPN being sent out, see if it is in a failed or retrying status.  Also look at the details of the IPN message and see if it shows the status code that is being returned back from your site.  The IPN system expects a 200ok response to be returned.  If there is a different status code, this may help to determine the cause of the issue.  Also, double check with your hosting provider if hosting with a 3rd party to make sure they haven't done any updates to firewalls or proxy's that may have affected your script.